# Twitter bootstrap: Label partly hidden behind text input when browser window width is not 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this problem with all the labels/inputs in my code. When my browser is in full screen it works fine, but when I minimize it even a bit, the input field steps over the label.

How do I avoid this?

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-1 control-label" for="input-username">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input id="input-username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username.." />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle for an example http://jsfiddle.net/2MdFf/

PS: Same goes for buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/9q949/

```
<div id="user-edit-buttons" class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="cancelUserEdit()">Avbryt</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="saveUser()">Lagre</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely why Bootstrap offers col sizing for multiple screens widths.  Your column contents are overflowing their containers due to the sizing of those elements.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1 control-label" for="input-username">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input id="input-username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username.." />
    </div>
</div>
```

They expect you to use different column sizes to make your elements work well in the different screen sizes.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thanks! Is this the only (read: best) way to do it? Doing it this way requires alot of trial and failing to get it perfect

Comment: Additionally, some of the column widths are a bit large (giving too much white space), but are still too small (overlapping) when only 1 width less is used. Is there no way working around this?